# XML serialization results in a file full of null characters

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, stream, corrupt-data

I'm serializing an object (of class Car) and saving it as an xml file. However sometimes (very rare event, I can't replicate it) I get a file that contains only null characters (characters with 0 ASCII code), even though the file size is correct.

```
public void SaveCar(Car car)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, car);
        byte[] binaryCar = stream.ToArray();
        FileHelper.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\car.xml", binaryCar);
    }
}
```

FileHelper.WriteAllBytes is the same as System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes, except that it creates the parent directory if it doesn't exist.

```
public static class FileHelper
{
    public static void WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
    {
        CreateParentDirectoryForPathIfDoesntExist(path);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
    }

    public static void CreateParentDirectoryForPathIfDoesntExist(string filePath)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (file.Directory != null && !file.Directory.Exists)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(file.Directory.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what can cause this? Encoding issues?

Comment: 'Sometimes' is when? For a specific file? A specific car? A [mcve] that reliably demonstrates the creation of a file with `NUL` chars would be useful.

Comment: And be more specific about `FileHelper`. That looks like a candidate problems source.

Comment: Include the code of `FileHelper` in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified it a little and added the FileHelper class. The problem is I can't replicate it (I have no idea what kind of data causes it to behave like that as the data is lost). It happens very rarely, and not even on my computer. Most of the time it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'SaveCar' method seams to work nicely, but I you want you can use following implementation

```
public class XmlCar {
    public static readonly Encoding Utf8Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    public static readonly XmlSerializer CarSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
    public static Car Load(string path) {
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(path, Utf8Encoding, false)) {
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)) {
                return (Car)CarSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Save(string path, Car instance) {
        using (var stream = new StreamWriter(path, false, Utf8Encoding)) {
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream)) {
                CarSerializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest difference from yours example is that serializer-instance is created once and UTF8 encoding is forced.

Your method was tried with following classes

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Car {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Plate { get; set; }
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem]
    public List<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot]
public class Part {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that this sample is derived from samples found on this site.

Yours method was changed a bit to accommodate some control over file name.

```
    public static void SaveCar(Car car, int i)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, car);
            byte[] binaryCar = stream.ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes("car"+ i + ".xml", binaryCar);
        }
    }
```

Method was tested with following function

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var random = new Random();
        var cars = new List<Car>();

        for (var c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            var car = new Car() {
                Model = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Plate = (random.Next(500) + 500).ToString(),
                Parts = new List<Part>()
            };
            for (var p = 0; p < 100; p++) {
                car.Parts.Add(new Part() {
                    Type = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Code = (random.Next(500) + 1500).ToString(),
                    Quantity = random.Next(100) + 1
                });
            }
            SaveCar(car, c);
            cars.Add(XmlCar.Load("car" + c + ".xml"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`XmlTextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`XmlTextWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) are not recommended (see the linked docs). You should use `XmlReader.Create` and `XmlWriter.Create`. `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` default to UTF8, though neither are required if you use the `Create` overloads that accept a file path. Though these changes don't do much harm, I don't see that they answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for trying to replicate in a loop, unfortunately I couldn't find the error this way either. if I don't find the cause of the error then I'll probably go with your solution, maybe the lack of encoding is what' causing the problem.

Comment: @Bedford, whenever writing to stream which you will read afterwards make sure that you have called Flush() on it (if supported, to ensure that all that is in). Also what may prove to be useful is to move position to beginning of the stream before next read.

Comment: @CharlesMager, thank you for pointing at bad sides of XmlTextReader/Writer. So far I have used them for app to app talk and within well constrained environments so there was no space for bad side to manifest.
About answer I do agree, it does not solve the issue but it does provide a workable sample which was used and tested many times.